# Amazon S3 prevent access to files from URLs

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-s3

I am working on an **iOS app**, and we recently started using **Amazon S3**, and I am not sure where to find information on this issue.

We are using S3 to store profile photos. We want to be able to download any user's *profile photo* and display it in the app. What we are doing is using the unique `profile ID` to create the *key* and upload the image to the *server*. Then, we can construct that same *URL* given a *profile ID*, and download profile images into the app.

However, there is concern that people will figure out the URL, and be able to view all of our users' profile images just by changing the `profile ID` component of the URL. The suggestion was to hash the key and then send it to S3, but we need to be able to create the same hash from multiple platforms (*iOS, Android, other apps, etc.*) to download images.

The solution was to send the key to the server, and have it send back the hashed response, and then begin uploading with the hashed key. This seems silly. If we wanted to download a user's profile photo in app we would have to get their user ID, then get the hash, then we could finally request the image.

I feel like there should be a way for us to securely upload and download images from our *website/apps*, but not allow an unauthenticated user to browse all images on the server. However, I have been unsuccessful in figuring out the best practice, and I was hoping someone could point me in the correct direction.

Answer (score 0):

I assume there is an additional API being used for the other information, like user info or posts, or whatever the app is for? Can you return a time-based expiry URL for the endpoint at that request? S3 supports links that expire at a given time, like 5 minutes from now or in 24 hours. Someone would have to figure out the path/endpoints for your API, your tokens used in the app, and then iterate through guessing the profile IDs to finally download the images.